# Why do people hide their nameservers?

Tags: dns

Sometimes when I look up the WHOIS information for some domains, I see that their nameservers are forwarded to a service like ZoneEdit or Domain Control. I've never understood what the purpose is for doing this but I have a feeling it has to do with hiding the nameserver so someone who does a WHOIS on the domain can't figure out which service the site is hosted under.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

There is all sorts of reasons someone may use a service like this:

- Their webhost doesn't provide DNS. Especially true for people running their own VPS (you'd need 2, for backup DNS).
- Their webhost provides DNS, but it is bad; it is slow, it drops out, whatever it may be.
- They use multiple webhosts and want to keep all the DNS in one place.

I'm sure there's many more, but these are the obvious ones.

On a related note, for many web hosts you can look up the owner of the IP range that the web server is in if you want to know what company is ultimately hosting a website. This will turn up some info, though the company that owns the IP may not be the person that is being paid directly by a site owner for hosting on that IP.